# Help me to retreive Account data in trigger

Tags: trigger

I am creating a service record when opportunity is closed won and product code in opportunity line item is null.  I am filling the new service record with the values from opportunity line item and opportunity, now they want data from account object, please help me to figure out this
When i uncomment the Account Acc....i get invalid foreign key relationship:opportunitylineitem.op

```
for (OpportunityLineItem oli:[SELECT OpportunityId,Product2.name
                              FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                              where ProductCode = null 
                              AND Opportunityid IN :opps]){
             Opportunity op = Trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId);
             // Account Acc = Trigger.newMap.get(oli.op.AccountId);
             lServ.add(new Services__c(
                     Account__c = op.accountid, 
                     Policy_Number__c=op.Policy_Number__c,
                     Opportunity__c=oli.OpportunityId,
                     Vendor__c =op.Issuing_Carrier__c,
                  // Source__c=Acc.Source__c,
                     Start_Date__c=op.Effective_Date__c, 
                     End_Date__c= op.Expiration_Date__c,
                     Product_Name__c=oli.Product2.name));                                                     
    }
    if (lServ.size() > 0){
        insert lServ;
    }
```

Comment: Your trigger is on which object? I wonder how your can get an `Opportunity` and `Account` from same `Map`. BTW, the relation should `opl.Opportunity.Account` if you have retrieved it in your SOQL query

Comment: trigger is on opportunity object.  I am new to this trigger area, so please help

Comment: Since you are already having the `Opportunity` object just get `Account` details from that.i.e. `Source__c=op.Account.Source__c` and same for any other `Account` fields

Comment: thank you so much, this helped me...if possible please suggest me any books to understand the relation between the objects and how to use them.

Comment: I have posted it as the answer below with more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trigger.newMap` will return a `Map` of triggered object with the new changes. So if you are writing the trigger on `Opportunity`, it will return a map of IDs to the new versions of the `Opportunity` records.
So after getting the `Opportunity` object from the `Map`, you are capable of retrieving it's parent with the existing relationships like below.

```
Account acc = op.Account;
```

Have a look at [Trigger Context variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) and note that,

> this map is only available in before update, after insert,
>   and after update triggers.

NOTE: Even though this is not directly relate to the question follow the best practices specially when writing triggers so that your [trigger support bulk records and not hitting governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).